# Docker return error DPI-1047: cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle library: libclntsh.so. Node.js Windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows, oracle, docker, node-oracledb

I'm using in docker container on windows 10 with nodejs. When I try to get data from oracle database - get request (the connection to data base in nodejs code) I get the message:
[image]

DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html for help

When I make a get request without the container(run server) the data was return well.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json app.js ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

connection to oracle:

```
async function send2db(sql_command, res) {
  console.log("IN");
  console.log(sql_command);
  try {
    await oracledb.createPool({
      user: dbConfig.user,
      password: dbConfig.password,
      connectString: dbConfig.connectString,
    });
    console.log("Connection pool started");
    const result = await executeSQLCommand(sql_command
      // { outFormat: oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT }
    );

    return result;
  } catch (err) {
    // console.log("init() error: " + err.message);
    throw err;
  }
}
```

Comment: You need a C client library.  The installation instructions in the error message link have at least a couple of pointers to get one; what have you tried already?

Comment: I downloaded this file and I added this code :
```
let libPath = "../instantclient_21_6/";

    if (libPath) {

      oracledb.initOracleClient({ libDir: libPath });
    }
```
and I got message: NJS-005: invalid value for parameter 1

Comment: That's not in your Dockerfile.  How does the shared library get into the image?

Comment: What I need to add to Dockerfile for this ?

Comment: You are running on Linux, not Windows in the container. Careful reading of the installation instructions for Linux shows `oracledb.initOracleClient({ libDir: libPath });` doesn't do what you want it to do on that OS.   However you may find it easier to refer to [Docker for Oracle Database Applications in Node.js and Python](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/part-1-docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python) which shows how to set your Dockerfiles, and also it has links to containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Docker for Oracle Database Applications in Node.js and Python](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/part-1-docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python) here is one solution:

```
FROM node:12-buster-slim

WORKDIR /opt/oracle

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libaio1 unzip wget
RUN wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip && \
    unzip instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip && \
    rm -f instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip && \
    cd instantclient* && \
    rm -f *jdbc* *occi* *mysql* *jar uidrvci genezi adrci && \
    echo /opt/oracle/instantclient* > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf && \
    ldconfig
```

You would want to use a later Node.js version now.  The referenced link shows installs on other platforms too.